# error during verification admob billing address

Tags: admob, adsense

> hey everyone.

> i have an admob that i started to use a while ago, i requested the pin but i haven't received it,  and while i was busy with some other stuff i did not request another one in time, then the Ads stop showing in my app, now i have made new request for pin verification second one , but i can't find a way how to restore ads while waiting another 2 or 3 weeks, is there a way to fix this, or i just keep waiting , if anyone has any suggestion or idea please share it.

> Thank you all.

---